# Off center Render and Wrapping

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation, video

OK While I'm rendering a video in cycles from frame by frame pre-rendered frame by frame sources or straight from the editor to a video format the scene is off center to the right and it seems to wrap around. There is a noticeable diagonal line on the left of the screen. Not Sure how to fix this I'd be grateful for some help. A bit more information each separately rendered frame looks right.[image]

[image]
1st pic is the render settings. As well as a camera view of the scene.
2nd is the render Issue I'm having when I attempt to render an animation. The full animation rendered this way both while rendering straight to an animation and also when rendering individual still frames then to an animation from those frames. But the individual Frames turned out perfectly fine.

I had attempted this on another scene prior to this but thought I had screwed something up while tweaking with the render setting there. I'm wondering if I somehow accidentally wrote the mess up to the startup file.

Comment: Please provide more info and screenshots of current setup + rendered results. As for now it seems that you render sequence of frames from VSE and *probably* have some effect clip which makes everything being moved / wrapped etc. It's hard to say exactly with info available.

Comment: OK Will do when I get back to my machine in the morning. I fugured that more info was needed but I wasn't sure what info.

Comment: Is the final resolution's width intentional ? 1921 is non standard.. and [h264 may cause issues](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20848224/3554425) when not using even width/height dimensions.

Comment: actually IT wouldn't render video when set to 1920 It said width not divisible by 2 (1919X1080) So I had to tweak it to 1921 to get it to work. Another small issue Is that When I came back from the store MY cat was on top of the keyboard so I had to fix things the best I could. I may just go with a fresh install and reapply all my settings. Dam that is going to take a while.